# Accessing MLxtend StackingRegressor attributes when the meta regressor is a sklearn pipeline object

Tags: scikit-learn, mlxtend

I am using [mlxtend](/questions/tagged/mlxtend) [package](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/) using [`StackingRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor.html) and my `meta_regressor` is a [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) package's pipeline object. After the model `fit()`, I want to print the coefficients, but I am having trouble doing that.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model3 = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(2), LinearRegression())
model4 = StackingRegressor(regressors=[model1, model2], meta_regressor=model3)
model4.fit(train, target)
print(model4.coef_) #1
print(model4.steps[1][1].coef_) #2
```

In #1, I get an error that `make_pipeline()` object has no attribute `coef_`, and in #2, I get an error that:

> StackingRegressor has no attribute steps.

Grateful for your assistance.